# Advice on Android Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, between

Good day and I am here to take some advice from you. Basically I have a class that has two methods as follows. It allows me to send data to the serial port (UART) and I receive data from it. Works fine.

Now, I have to modify it in such a way that it will send some data  to the serial port **serialPort.writeBytes(src.getBytes());** and wait for the reply for 3 seconds, if I get a reply in between 3 seconds it has to be updated to a TextView and if not it has to send the second data  (**serialPort.writeBytes(src1.getBytes());**)and again wait for the reply.

I am not an expert in Threads and Handlers as I have just started to learn it. Please advise me on this. Thank you very much for your time.

```
public void sendData(){
    final String src = "MYDATA\r";
    final String src1 = "MYDATA1\r";
    serialPort.writeBytes(src.getBytes());
    **// Pause here and wait for the reply**
    serialPort.writeBytes(src1.getBytes());
   **//  Pause here and wait for reply**
}




private class ReadThread extends Thread {
    byte[] buf = new byte[512];

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            int size;
            if (mInputStream == null)
                return;
            size = serialPort.readBytes(buf);

            if (size > 0) {

                byte[] dest = new byte[size];
                System.arraycopy(buf, 0, dest, 0, size);
                byteLinkedList.offer(dest);
                onDataReceived();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now

Comment: I would add the Java tag to get more view as this is not exclusive of Android. Regarding your question, I would call sendData() from inside a Thread run method and after sending the first bytes call readData() and do a Thread.sleep(3000), then just check if you received the data (that would mean the 3 seconds already passed) and send the second chunk of bytes if not or do nothing if data was received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer, I cant comment cause I don't have enough rep.

I agree with momo. So you will have something like this:

```
class SendThread extends Thread{

    boolean gotData = false; //flag to check if data is received.

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(gotData == false){
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    //SendData code
                    //if you get Data change gotData = true;
                }
            }.run();
            Thread.sleep(3000); //sleep for 3 secs
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a complex situation, you can use the Android `AsyncTask` - do a search and you will find a lot of references to it.

Essentially, you need an interface that you can call to respond when the data is received. Polling is a matter of calling `wait` on this thread. If you are not familiar with wait, you can also search easily for it.

The key issue is that the UI should not `wait` and with a thread or AsyncTask it will not.

If you decide to use threads, then look into creating a simple "listener" (aka `interface`). It might seem intimidating, but basically it is an empty class that you will need to pass into your custom thread.

Also, you may need to consider if your Activity will still be visible during this process. If it might not be, and you still need to complete the task in the background, you will need a `Service`

This is a good "overview" of your options: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Since you really haven't defined the full use-case, you probably need to do more research or be more specific. But this should get you going in the right direction.